# 2 Level CSS Drop Down Menu - display: none Does not Work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have designed a 2-Level CSS drop down menu. Everything works perfect except only one thing. I want it so that when I hover over the top menu item, the 1st level drop down menu appears and when I hover over the item **Press** in the 1st level menu then the 2nd level menu items appear. But the problem is that when I hover over the top menu all sub-menus appear altogether. That means the `display: none` does not work. Why does it happen and what is the solution?

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/infinity/2J4e3/)

HTML Code

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="/ueber_uns.htm">About Us</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code

```
ul#nav 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
/*display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;*/
}
ul#nav li
{
float: left;
position: relative;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: orange;
}
ul#nav li li
{
font-size: 14px;
}
ul#nav ul 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
display: none;
}
ul#nav li:hover ul 
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
ul#nav a:link, ul#nav a:visited
{
display: block;
width: 110px;
padding: 10px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
ul#nav ul a:link, ul#nav ul a:visited 
{
width: 135px;
}
ul#nav a:hover, ul#nav a:active
{
color: #fff;
}
ul#nav ul ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
display: none;
}
ul#nav ul li:hover ul
{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
ul#nav li:hover ul 
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

to this

```
ul#nav li:hover > ul 
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2J4e3/1/)

Basically what `ul#nav li:hover > ul` does is that it targets the secondary drop-down menu only, so when you hover over about us, only the second level menu is going to show up, leaving the third one hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
li:hover ul
```

will apply to all descendant `ul`. Change it to this:

```
li:hover>ul
```

to apply to direct descendant.

Answer (score 0):

Use immediate child selector `>`

http://jsfiddle.net/2J4e3/2/